# How to add a logo on the first page in R using Ioslides

Tags: r, ioslides

ioslides_presentation:
widescreen: true
smaller: true
transition: slower
template: quarterly-report.html
logo: cap1.png

I have been trying many different ways to to add a logo into ioslides, but I have been unsuccessful. The documentation of ioslides only states that to add a logo just write "logo:logo.png" on the YALM header, yet that does not work and it is widely vague

Please give a set of instructions on how to add the logo

Answer (score 0):

To add a logo you need to make sure the file is in your folder or that you provide the path. I removed the template part because I don't have one now.

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "author"
date: "2/15/2021"
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    logo: logo.png
    widescreen: true 
    smaller: true 
    transition: slower
---
```